# Restart Android Kiosk App after any interruption

Tags: android, restart, kiosk-mode

I'm working on a Android 11 Kiosk app (so this app is not for end user devices), and sometimes I found it closed in the morning without any logs in logcat.

I spent much time to understand why my app close, without luck, and now I wish to know if the way to restart the app, (considering the device is rooted) is shorter.

In Debian like system I can use systemctl restart option, but how to make somethings similar with android?